# Index column header based on value in row Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, max

I have a large excel file of water accumulation values for column headers, and site locations for row headers. I'm trying to determine the largest accumulation value (ie: column header) for each row in my dataset. My data looks as follows:

[image]

The values in each cell are irrelevant; the only part that's important is whether or not the cell value is greater than 0. I'd like to add this information on as an additional column that tells me the largest accumulation value (the column header) each site had a value for:

[image]

I know I can use the index function, but I'm only able to get it to return max CELL values, not the max COLUMN HEADER for which there's a cell value > 0. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Function I've tried:
=INDEX(B1:L1,MATCH(MAX(B2:L2),B2:L2,0))

Comment: That exact formula works for me when I try it.  You'll need to make sure to use absolute positioning on the header row, so the formula in cell M2 should be: `=INDEX(B$1:L$1,MATCH(MAX(B2:L2),B2:L2,0))` and then just copy it down

Comment: Based on the image, it looks like the formula you currently have in cell M2 and copied down is `=COUNTIF(B2:L2,">0")` which returns how many cells had values greater than 0

Comment: @tigeravatar  Thanks for trying to help with this! The function I'm currently using returns the column with the greatest cell value, which is not what I'm after. I'm trying to find the largest column header value for each row that contains a value larger than 0. Example: for row 2 where SITEid = 23011195007, the largest column value that has an associated cell value>0 is Value_10. For row 3 where SITEid=23011196005, that would be Value_9. Any htoughts?

Comment: Typo, sorry! I meant to say row 3 = 23011195006.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but might serve, in M2 and copied down:

```
="VALUE_"&IF(L2<>0,10,IF(K2<>0,9,IF(J2<>0,8,IF(I2<>0,7,IF(H2<>0,6,IF(G2<>0,5,IF(F2<>0,4,IF(E2<>0,3,IF(D2<>0,2,IF(C2<>0,1,"NA"))))))))))
```

Comment: This would definitely work if I only had 10 columns. Unfortunately the question above is only a portion of my dataset; the full dataset contains 300+ columns. Any thoughts on a way to streamline the function?

Comment: I certainly could. Replace with a blank cell or an "NA" value?

Comment: Can you explain the "1E+100" portion? I just tried the function and am getting an incorrect value for the column.